# How to fetch a specific document from inside the subcollection

Tags: flutter, firebase, listview, google-cloud-firestore

I'm developing a password manager app using flutter and firebase as a backend service and database. I have a database with a collection of users, and inside users there is a subcollection named passwordProfiles that have a number of documents inside it.

Using listview.build I managed to fetch all the documents inside that subcollection.  Now I want to only fetch a 1 specific document inside the subcollection.  How can I achieve that?

Below is the link to my github repo: https://github.com/Tron987/prog.git

Answer (score 0):

From your `pubspec.yaml` file I see you use **Firestore** as your database backend instead of **Realtime Database** which can be confused as both are Firebase products.

To query a single document you need to use `DocumentSnapshot` return from **Firestore**. [Here is the complete Firestore query documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage) which details how to get values from Collections full of documents or just a single Document with it's ID or it's values.

As you are just trying to get a single document [this is the exact part](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#documentsnapshot) that you must check.

Comment: I tried reading that documentation but it did not help